# Is there any out of the box code to serialize a model to Key Value Pairs using ModelMetaData?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelmetadata

I know that ModelMetadata is used to bind values from a model to fields.  Is there any out of the box MVC code that will take a model and use it's ModelMetadata to generate KeyValuePairs for the values of all of it's properties?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the .ToDictionary() extension method from System.Linq?

```
Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.ToDictionary(key => key.PropertyName, value => value.Model);
```

Comment: I would not be calling this from code where the ViewData is available.  I guess the way to start is to construct the ViewData to get to that point.